# Windows Store Apps: Client -Server connectivity?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to develop a Windows 8.1 app that uses a client-server model to send some data from the server to multiple clients through Wifi or within a network.

the functionality is similar to what's in this app http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb/app/67786fc8-b27b-4ea1-92f5-1ad8abfbeda1

would you please guide me to the APIs or concepts to use to achieve such functionality ?

Comment: Check out [`DatagramSocket.JoinMulticastGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.joinmulticastgroup).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, what about WiFi direct, can we use it in a similar scenario ?